# laravel: implementing section from a pulled-in subview

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Here's the structure of my templates:

```
master
  @yield('master1')
  @yield('master2')
dashboard
  @extends('master')
  @section('master1')
  @include('sub-1')
submaster
  @yield('submaster1')
sub-1
  @extends('submaster')
  @section('submaster1')
  @section('master2') <-- this is what I am trying to do
```

Here's a more visual representation

```
master                       submaster
 @yield('master1')            @yield('submaster1')
 @yield('master2')              |
  |                             |
  |___ dashboard                |
        @extends('master')      |
        @section('master1')     |
        @include('sub-1')       |
          |                     |
          |_______ sub-1 _______|
                    @extends('submaster')
                    @section('submaster1') <-- from the right
                    @section('master2') <-- from the left
```

Is this kind of thing possible with Blade? when I remove the implementation of `master2` from `sub-1`, everything works fine.  when I add it back in, the code from `submaster` continues to render, the code in `master2` seems to work and get included in the expected place, but the code in `submaster1` stops getting included in the appropriate sections in `submaster`.

Comment: can you add also where you put `@stop`

Comment: At the end of every `@section`. That was the first thing I checked.